# Drawing over image view with condition not working in Android?

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin

A user can draw over an image by swiping over the image view. I have a boolean condition defined in my class that should be checked before anything is drawn over the image. Only if this condition is true, then the user can swipe over to draw over the image.
So I registered my image view for an OnTouch event listener.

```
pictureBox1.SetOnTouchListener(this);
```

The in class condition to check before drawing

```
private bool fingerEnabled = false;
```

How I override the OnTouch to draw over the image view

```
public bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
 {
     switch (e.Action)
     {
         case MotionEventActions.Down:
             if (fingerEnabled)
             {
                 path.Reset();
                 path.MoveTo(e.GetX(), e.GetY());
                 downX = e.GetX();   
                 downY = e.GetY();
                 return true;
             }
             break;
         case MotionEventActions.Move:
             if (fingerEnabled)
             {
                 float x = e.GetX();
                 float y = e.GetY();
                 float dx = Math.Abs(x- downX);  
                 float dy = Math.Abs(y- downY);
                 if(dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE)
                 {
                     path.QuadTo(downX, downY,(x+downX)/2,(y+downY)/2);
                     downX = x;
                     downY = y;
                     v.Invalidate(); 
                 }
                 return true;
             }
             break;
         case MotionEventActions.Up:
             if (fingerEnabled)
             {
                 path.LineTo(downX, downY);
                 v.Invalidate();
                 return true;
             }
             break;
     }
     return false;   
 }
```

There is a button that acts as a toggle for drawing on and drawing off, here is the code that handles that

```
private void Draw_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
 if(fingerEnabled == false){
    fingerEnabled = true;
    path = new Android.Graphics.Path();
    paint = new Paint  
    {
      Color = Color.Chartreuse,
      StrokeWidth = 5f,
      AntiAlias = true, 
      StrokeJoin = Paint.Join.Round,
      StrokeCap = Paint.Cap.Round
    };
    Toast.MakeText(this,"Swipe your finger over the image to draw", ToastLength.Short).Show();
   }else{
    fingerEnabled = false;
    Toast.MakeText(this,"drawing over image disabled", ToastLength.Short).Show();
  } 
}
```

Why is this code not drawing over my image view when the switch is toggled?

Comment: does it work without the button?  Have you stepped through the code in the debugger?

Comment: @Jason,No, clicking the button changes the condition to true and then tried to draw but whether on or off it doesn't draw

Comment: Then the conditional really has nothing to do with your problem.  Again, have you stepped through the code in the debugger?  Is it doing what you expect?

Comment: @Jason, are you able to draw from your end? No I haven't tried the debugger